# How do I autocreate associated records in MongoDB using Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongoid, associations, autocreate

I'm still getting my head around `MongoDB` and `Mongoid` in particlar.

Let's say I have a `User` and each `User` has one `Thingamajig`.  When I create the `User`
I want the system to autmatically also create a blank `Thingamajig` for that `User`.

Each `Thingamajig` has a `whatsit` field that must be unique if it has a value, but is allowed to have no value when created.

So I define the following classes.

```
class Thingamajig
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :whatsit, type: String
  index({whatsit: 1}, {unique: true, name: 'whatsit_index'})
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  index({name: 1}, {unique: true, name: 'user_name_index'})
  embeds_one :thingamajig, dependent: :nullify, autobuild: true
end
```

However what I find when I

```
User.create!(name: 'some name')
```

is that `User.find(name: 'some name').thingamajig` is nil.

Questions:

1. How can I ensure that each User gets an associated Thingamajig? and
2. How do I specify that the `name` field of a `User` is required?

FYI I am using `Sintara` not `Rails` (if that matters to anyone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - The `autobuild: true` option normally should have done the trick. I think the problem is that you forgot to add the other side of the relation to the Thingamajig model:

```
class Thingamajig
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :user
  ...
end
```

2 - To specify required fields, use [validations](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/validation.html):

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  validates_presence_of :name
  ...
end
```

Mongoid uses [ActiveModel validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html).

Comment: I assume there's an equivalent `validates_uniqueness_of` too.

Comment: Yup. ActiveModel/Mongoid give you lots of validations to play with. (See the link I added.)